# specify range mininclusive and maxinclusive xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

I am a beginner at defining own xsd for xml schemas. I am just wondering if there is a way to specify min and max inclusive with attribute value rather than writing the number each time. This is just an pseudoexample of what I was thinking if it was possible in xsd:

```
    <xs:complexType name="postNumberRang">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="rangePostNr">
                <xs:attribute name="minimum" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger"/>
                <xs:attribute name="maximum" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="rangePostNr">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
          <xs:minInclusive value="minimum"/>
          <xs:maxInclusive value="maximum"/>
      </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. (Expressing your requirements by inventing syntax that you hope will be self-explanatory is not a recommended technique.)

I suspect you are trying to define the constraints on one attribute in terms of the values of other attributes on the same element. That's known as a "co-occurrence constraint" and is not possible in XSD 1.0. It can be done in XSD 1.1 using assertions or using conditional type assignment. So you need to decide whether your project is able to take advantage of XSD 1.1.